# "error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token" at position of memset invocation

Tags: c++, g++

In the above code I'm getting an error with G++ at the memset invocation, saying `error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token`. What's the possible reason?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<utility>
#include<algorithm>
#include<list>
#include<cstring>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int visited[1000];
memset(visited,0,sizeof(visited)); 
^ //This is where the error points to.

void dfs(vector< list< pair<int,int> > > graph,int u)
{
    visited[u]=1;
    cout<<u<<" ";

    list< pair<int,int> >::iterator x=graph[u].begin();
    for(;x!=graph[u].end();x++)
        if(!visited[x->first])
            dfs(graph,x->first);
}

int main()
{
    int v,e;
    cout<<"Vertices,edges?\n";
    cin>>v>>e;
    vector< list< pair<int,int> > > graph(v+1);
    for(int i=1;i<=e;i++)
    {
        int source,dest,weight;
        cin>>source>>dest>>weight;
        graph[source].push_back(make_pair(dest,weight));
    }
    list< pair<int,int> >::iterator p;
    int i=1;
    while(i<=v)
    {
        p=graph[i].begin();
        for(;p!=graph[i].end();p++)
            cout<<i<<" "<<p->first<<" : weight is "<<p->second<<"\n";
        i++;
    }
    dfs(graph,1);cout<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

It would also be really helpful if you could provide tips for me to improve my code/coding practice. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

`std::memset`, as is the case for any function, can only be called within a *function*.

You can't simply call it in "global scope", if you get my meaning. That's what's confusing the compiler.

In your particular case, you don't need the `memset` call as global variables are zero-initialised in C++.

Consider also replacing `#include<stdlib.h>` with the C++ header `#include <cstdlib>`.

Comment: Or better still, just understand that `visited` is zero-filled on inception anyway (its a global). I.e. the `memset` is pointless.

Comment: Nicked that, and wiki'd the answer.